# Show first 5 lines every file without name

Tags: linux, terminal

I need to show first 5 lines of every file inside my home folder but without showing name of the file. I know that has something to do with `head -n 5` command and I know I can list files using `ls -al|grep ^-` but I don't know how to combine that knowledge to solve my problem. Any tips?

Comment: Just use the `-q` option of `head` to suppress headers: `head -q -n 5 *  2> /dev/null`. Directories are ignored automatically, but give an error message you can suppress.

Comment: I am not sure if my teacher would find it good enough but works for me, thanks :)

Comment: Instead of `ls -al | grep ^-`, you might prefer `ls -ap | grep -v /$`

Answer (score 2):

This uses `find` to find all regular files in the home dir without (recursing into subdirectories), and passes them on to `head`:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec head -q -n 5 '{}' '+'
```